# Considerations for using a dropdown with multiple inputs and selections in a table row to add additional scenarios

Tags: tables, dropdown, multi-step

Please see the mockup up example. The scenario is to set an initial price, then the user can use the dropdown down to set dates in the future that the user can either increase or decrease the price by selecting a checkmark in the dropdown and entering the price and date that the price will become active. The second two inputs do not become active until the first checkmark is used. The two following checkmarks can't be dates in the past of the first checkmark.
[image]

I'm thinking of adding a small set button at the bottom of the dropdown so we can have the user confirm their choices and provide feedback. If not the user would just click out of the dropdown and dismiss it like any other dropdown. Are there any other considerations or concerns that would need addressing with how the table row reads and the interaction with the dropdown to set additional settings?

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the dropdown pattern altogether for the Price Overrides column and replace it with an "Add Override" link button that opens a modal window. In the modal, you can do a full CRUD editing pattern for the overrides with an Update and Cancel button at the bottom to apply changes. No checkboxes needed on each row, just make them active by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think having a "confirm" and "cancel"  buttons makes sense on the popup, instead of check boxes as user can enter the input in the rows he/she would like to change for and then he hits confirm to proceed further. Also, for other two check boxes, the calendar which opens up should not highlight the past date as you have mentioned the date cannot be in the past. When the user has entered the information in the drop down and hit the "confirm" button , the row can expand to accomodate other "changes options" and  "edit" icon can appear in the row to bring out further changes.